# Edit saved filters directly in search input box in Odoo 9 Listview

Tags: python-2.7, listview, search, odoo, odoo-9

Is there anyway we can edit saved filters and search input datas directly in searchbox? Or can we save current search domain for current session only?? The datas in search input field in list view should be preserved for current session.

If I save the domains in ir.filters and make it as default only name of the is shown when I reload. I want to have all filters name and value in search box?

Comment: No right now odoo does not have such functionality.

Comment: Yes. Odoo doesnot have this functionality. I would  appreciate any help.